# Sql Server adding another user

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a Database say TestDatabase.I have already added an user under 
NTAuthority\SYSTEM(Role) Db_owner.

Again i wish to add another user to the same Database under NTAuthority\System with
different role.

I received the following error :

```
The login already has an accoind under different username.

SQL Server Error :15063
```

How can i add different users to the same database with different role.

I would appreciate if i receive elobarate explanation.

Comment: Please unmark this question as Community Wiki. CW is usually for objective questions with no "real" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You add the same user to multiple roles.

db_owner already has all rights anyway withing the database so any other permissions are superfluous.

```
CREATE USER [NTAuthority\SYSTEM] FROM LOGIN [NTAuthority\SYSTEM];
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'NTAuthority\SYSTEM'
-- ...and fails
CREATE USER [bob] FROM LOGIN [NTAuthority\SYSTEM];

--Normally, for one user in multiple roles
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'DoStuff', 'NTAuthority\SYSTEM'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'DoSpecialStuff', 'NTAuthority\SYSTEM'
--... and for another user
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'DoStuff', 'AnotherUser'
--... and for yet another user
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'DoLimitedStuff', 'TheThirdUser'
```

Edit:

Look at the MS documentation: [Database-Level Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx) and the parent [Identity and Access Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510418.aspx) topic

Comment: Then what is the possibility of having the role based authentication on same DB?

Comment: Good Explanation.It gives the full details of what i expected.

Answer (score 0):

1. if is db_owner there is no point in adding him to any other role.
2. to add an existing user to a new role you run [sp_roleaddmember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx)

Comment: Pls let me know how can i achieve two different roles having different rights on same DB.